# Dropping consecutive duplicate rows, duplication only for 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example of a dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', 'vegetable'],
                    'name': ['orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'leek', 'spinach', 'spinach', 'spinach'],
                    'value': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '700']})
```

I want to remove consecutive duplicate rows that are only duplicates for:

```
test['type']

test['name']
```

I've seen that a common solution is to use shift if it was for the entire dataframe or an individual column

```
# for a particular column

test[test.name != test.name.shift()]
```

I there anyway to have it span 2 columns?

Thank you so much for any insight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple with `tuple`

```
s = pd.Series(zip(test.type, test.name), test.index)
test[s != s.shift()]

        type     name value
0      fruit   orange   100
2      fruit    apple   300
3      fruit    grape   400
4  vegetable     leek   500
5  vegetable  spinach   600
```

Answer (score 3):

2 Columns with an `any` on `axis=1`:

```
test[test[['type','name']].ne(test[['type','name']].shift()).any(1)]
```

---

```
        type     name value
0      fruit   orange   100
2      fruit    apple   300
3      fruit    grape   400
4  vegetable     leek   500
5  vegetable  spinach   600
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way but may not work if row is duplicated one after another is;

Set as multi index

```
 test.set_index(['type','name'], inplace=True)
```

Drop multiindex duplicates

```
test = test.loc[~test.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Reset index

```
 test.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: IIUC: the key issue is that OP wants "consecutive duplicates".  I took that to mean when duplicated one row after another.  If it were to be duplicated several rows afterwards, it wouldn't count.

Comment: Aha, Fair enough. Will leave it there with your comment underscored

Comment: Actually this suggestion might be super useful, I want to see how it performs for more than row per row duplications.